# Back Button in the Navigation Bar not Working?

Tags: android

I have created an android project, with a couple of activities.
I have also added the back button feature into the activities, however when I click it
nothing happens.

Have I done something wrong?
I've put this code into each of the activities, and none of them work

Any opinion/input is greatly appreciated.

Code for trying to go back from my Gallery activity to the main:

```
 //GalleryActivity.java

 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // return true;

      MenuInflater mif = getMenuInflater();
      mif.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

and.. in res/menu/

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/back_icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back"
    android:title="@string/back_title"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

I downloaded the proper android design icons, and have added them to the drawable folders too.

EDIT:

Main Activity

```
    button4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);//find the button

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), GalleryActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);
             finish();//close main activity after start info activity
             }
         });// links to gallery page
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` and check for the id. For instance:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.back_icon:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: When I fixed it and added the above...the button works...but it brings me out of the project to home screen...I want the back button on all activities to return to Main. But i guess its on the right track

Comment: I see. Did you call finish() on the MainActivity?

Comment: Hmm... no.. I didnt think i'd need anything in main.. ? Sorry to have to ask.. but, finish() ?

Comment: It does not make sense. If I have not misunderstood, you have two activities. From the MainActivity you go to SecondActivity, which override  `onOptionsItemSelected`, am I wrong?

Comment: I have a main activity...with a button to a second. When I am in the second activity, i want to be able to press back to bring me back to main

Comment: ok then, if you do not call finish() on the MainActivity, after you started the second's one, it should work the way you want to. Can you post the code where do you start the second activity?

Comment: I've added the full Main Activity and Second Activity, so u can see what i have done exactly. Thanks for the help

Comment: as I said, do not call finish(). `button4.setOnClickListener` after startActivity, you call finish(). Remove it

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the action of the options, included the home/back action as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {

        case R.id.back_icon:
            onBackPressed(); //Or whatever you want to do when back_icon is pressed!
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

}
```